# How to use PATINDEX in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012, patindex

In SQL Server 2012, I have a column which has long text data. Somewhere within the text, there is some text of the format

```
{epa_file_num} = {138410-81}
```

If it exists, I want to extract out `138410-81` as a column value. In regular JS regex, I would use something like this `{ *epa_file_num *} *= *{ *\d*-?\d* *}` to match the column, and then maybe a capturing group to get the value.

But how can I get it in SQL Server 2012?

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support reg-ex or capturing groups. PATINDEX basically gives you the ability to do very primitive pattern matching, more like the "LIKE" command.

Comment: Is there no way to use a combination of Pattindex, and substings to get the value?

Comment: I'd write a utility in some other language to read the value and do whatever complex string parsing you need... a C# utility that uses RegEx for example. Trying to hack something together into SQL that does what you want will be complicated, time-consuming, and error-prone. This just isn't what SQL is designed for.

Comment: @pmbAustin many dialects do support regexp extraction. I'm surprised Sql Server does not

Answer (score 0):

Not a regex, but this might do what you want:

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(MAX)='{some name} = {a value} some text {epa_file_num} = {138410-81} other text'
SET @Input=REPLACE(@Input,' ','')
SET @Input=SUBSTRING(@Input,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%{epa_file_num}={%',@Input),0)+LEN('{epa_file_num}={'),LEN(@Input))
SET @Input=SUBSTRING(@Input,1,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('}',@Input),0)-1)
SELECT @Input
```

First, I remove all the spaces, then I look for `{epa_file_num}=` and take everything after this string, until the next `}`.